# How can i add a crisp variable as a LinguisticVariable in AForge.net Fuzzy Rule

Tags: c#, fuzzy

I have a question about the Aforge.Fuzzy Library. I would like to use light (red,orange,green) as condition in the rules, but i don't know how can i add it as a linguistic variable.

I have those three linguistic variables :

```
var lvSpeedIn = new LinguisticVariable("Speed", 0.0f, 0.4f);
var lvDistance = new LinguisticVariable("Distance", 10, 90);
var lvBreak = new LinguisticVariable("Break", -0.4f, 0.0f);
```

My rule has to be like this :

```
inferenceSys.NewRule("Rule 1", "IF Light IS Red AND Speed IS Fast AND Distance IS Close THEN Break IS LOW");
```

Could someone help me to create the light variable that is not a fuzzy variable.

Comment: Can someone help me please ??

Comment: Thank you, i found the solution : 
 
                 `FuzzySet fsRed = new FuzzySet("Red",
                 new SingletonFunction(1));
             FuzzySet fsGreen = new FuzzySet("Green",
                 new SingletonFunction(2));
             FuzzySet fsOrange = new FuzzySet("Orange",
                 new SingletonFunction(3));

             LinguisticVariable lvLight = new LinguisticVariable("Light",1,3);
             lvLight.AddLabel(fsRed);
             lvLight.AddLabel(fsGreen);
             lvLight.AddLabel(fsOrange);`